# Помогите с Php и MYSQL

Tags: php, denwer, mysql

Здравствуйте я начинающий webmaster я вчера установил denwer и скачал самоучитель по php и у меня к вам 2 маленьких вопроса:
1)Зачем нужен MYSQL ?
2)Почему когда я пишу php файл с любой кодировкой (я уже все кодировки перепробовал получается одго и тоже)  с кодом:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Мой первый PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
$mydate=date("Y.m.d"); 
echo "<span style='color: red;'>",$mydate,"</span>"; 
echo"<br>", __file__;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

и когда загружаю с автоопределением кодировки то получается

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>РњРѕР№ РїРµСЂРІС‹Р№ PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<span style='color: red;'>2011.05.19</span><br>Z:\home\rules.ru\www\index.php</body>
</html>
```

если ставлю кодировку utf-8 то тело документа исправляется а title всё тотже РњРѕР№ РїРµСЂРІС‹Р№ PHP
и браузер игнарирует даже строку

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

Помогите исправить и чё делать и ответьте для чего всётаки MYSQL ?

Comment: Понял раньше был глупый задал такой глупый вопрос теперь поумнел вырос.. И такие глупые вопросы задавать больше не буду :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для того чтобы денвер работал в кодировке utf-8 необходимо следующее - в файле **webserversusrlocalapacheconfhttpd.conf** найти строчку **AddDefaultCharset**. Если после неё стоит **windows-1251**, то закоментируем её, и напишем свою. Должно получиться так:

```
#
# Denwer: default charset.
#
#AddDefaultCharset windows-1251

AddDefaultCharset UTF-8
```

Теперь перезагрузим денвер, и все должно работать хорошо.

Для того чтобы PHP работал с MySQL тоже в кодировке UTF-8 надо в файле **webserversusrlocalmysql5my.cnf**

Сделать вот так:

```
#
# Параметры MySQL-сервера.
#
[mysqld]
# Использовать режим совместимости с клиентами MySQL 3.x и MySQL 4.0.
old-passwords

# Кодировка баз данных по умолчанию.
#default-character-set = cp1251
#init-connect = "set names cp1251"

default-character-set = utf8
init-connect = "set names utf8"
skip-character-set-client-handshake
```

Здесь мы комментировали кодировку windows-1251 и вместо неё включили utf-8.

Answer (score 4):

1. MySQL - для хранения данных. В сети полно информации с описаниями и примерами, поэтому не буду переписывать весь интернет сюда. Или задай вопрос конкретнее, отвечу.
2. Дело в том, что твой редактор сохраняет текст в формате Windows-1251 (или любой другой кодировке, отличной от UTF-8). Сохрани файл в кодировке UTF-8 и будет тебе счастье.

Comment: Я тоже думал что это редактор но у меня dreamweawer и он севершенноточно сохраняет в utf 8 и ктомуже почему браузе угнорирует метатег???

Comment: Скопировал твой первый код, сохранил в UTF-8. Открыл страницу - всё нормально. Как объяснишь?

Comment: А!! я понял я в блокноте сохранил в ansci и всё ок а вот с utf 8 кокразтаки файл и неработал! я незнаю почему у тебя в utf сработало магия какаето!

Comment: Никакой магии - только опыт.

Comment: - скопируй код
- удали из файла все
- сохрани файл как utf-8
- вставь код

Answer (score 3):

2. Браузер может игнорировать кодировку из мета-тега "Content-Type", если уже была передана кодировка в соответствующем заголовке. Т.е. к примеру, если следующий код сохранить в UTF-8, то он так-же, в зависимости от браузера, может выдавать крякозябры:

`<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=windows-1251', true); ?>`

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Мой первый PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
Мой первый PHP
</body>
</html>
```

Не исключено, что денвер настроен так, что всегда выдает Content-Type с кодировкой windows-1251. Соответственно, в этом случае нужно либо настроить денвер, что бы выдавал корректный заголовок, либо явно передавать заголовок: `<?php header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8', true); ?>`

Comment: Спасибо громадное! Помогло (не то что предыдущие "советы"). Я проголосую за вас! Если что ещё подскажете, тут как раз у меня новый вопрос насчёт php - я скоро спрошу!

Answer (score -2):

О [MySQL](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL).

Пробуй вот так:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Мой первый PHP</title>
</head>
<body>
<span style="color:red;">2011.05.19</span><br>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: > Мой первый PHP
Кроме HTML с кучей ошибок, больше ничего нет!